# Adding aspects to maven project

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

I created `aspectJ` class in seperate Maven project:

```
@Aspect
public class AspectE {

    @Pointcut("execution(@EntryPoint * *.*(..))")
    public void defineEntryPoint() {
    }

    @Before("defineEntryPoint()")
    public void setThreadName(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
       ...
    }

    @After("defineEntryPoint()")
    public void removeThreadName(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in second project I annotated several methods and added to `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>first-project</groupId>
        <artifactId>first-project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But still aspects aren't *seen* at all. Am I missing some steps? What should I do?

Comment: Adding the AspectJ runtime is not enough, you need to activate the aspectj compiler as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to weave correctly your code with your libraries, you should declare them within your dependencies AND within the aspectj weaver:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Aspectj lib  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-aspect-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other dependencies -->

</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- Specific build configuration -->

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>com.my.group</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my-aspect-lib</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Other plugins configuration -->

    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- Other settings -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you take a look at this?

[AspectJ compiler Maven Plugin - Usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to weave the aspects with the code. This can be done in 2 ways:

- Compile-time weaving, using the [AspectJ compiler Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/usage.html) as Andrei suggested
- [Load-time weaving (LTW)](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw.html), using an agent or a custom class-loader

Load-time weaving is a bit more versatile, but can be a bit challenging to set up properly. It consumes more CPU during startup (when the weaving happens), and also has a memory footprint.
Compile-time weaving consumes more CPU during the compilation, obviously, but then you don't pay the price on each restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ... but after I added this maven repo it's working

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```